# Put a line beside my text by css

Tags: html, css

I want to put a line beside my text Like THIS

**----- Hello WOrld -----**

the line should be continued and BOLD and align side middle wise And RED

Comment: You should have communicated in the right way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried :before and :after selectors?

```
<span class="dashes">Hello WOrld</span>

<style type="text/css">
 .dashes { font-weight: bold; }
 .dashes:before, .dashes:after { content:"----"; color:#f00; }
</style>
```

This is how it comes out: [image sample](http://o7.no/UseBTy)

**UPDATE**

Based on your updates and comments, I think this fits your description:

```
<h4 class="sidelines"><span>Hello WOrld</span></h4>
<style type="text/css">
h4.sidelines { text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #f00; height: 0.5em; }
h4.sidelines span { display: inline-block; background: #fff; padding:0 0.25em; }
</style>
```

This will give you a centered, bolded title with continuous lines on each side.

Here's an example of the update: http://o7.no/PVXvaH

Comment: But the line should not be doted it should be continued.And the  **font-weight** should be more bold .

Comment: It should be noted as in @Sibizulu's comment, that this isn't compatible in all browsers, but the correct approach none the less. As per a solid line; that's another question. Is there a content-image attribute?

Comment: I don't want ------ this type of line is it possible put a line like **line-through** HTML Tag

Comment: You want a solid line? Just change the 'dotted' part to 'solid' and you're good.

Answer (score 2):

No css required

```
&boxh;&boxh;&boxh;&nbsp;Hello World&nbsp;&boxh;&boxh;&boxh;
```

Looks like this
──── Hello World ────

Answer (score 1):

try this. but not compatible for all browser versions.

```
 p:before,p:after  {
  content: "---";
 }

<p>Hello WOrld</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using `div`'s. check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/yJ2AF/2/) to see the result.

**HTML**

```
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="text">Hello WOrld</div>
<div class="line"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.line
{
  width:100px;background-color:black;
  border: 0.1em solid black; /* dashed, groove, inset */
  margin-top:0.45em;margin-bottom:0.45em;
}

.line, .text
{
  float:left;
}

.text
{
  padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;
}
```

Remember that when you add the scales(height) of `margin-top`, `margin-bottom` and `border`, it should be equal to one. Like `0.45 + 0.45 + 0.1 = 1` in my example. This will keep layout clean.

If you want to make the lines more bold then just increase the scale of `border` keeping in mind about the scales of `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello World

```css
p {
    text-align:center;
    border-left: 50px solid #363454;
    border-right: 50px solid #363454;
    width:150px;
    line-height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?. Thanks